# Java and Sip Proxy

Tags: proxy, sip, sip-server

I was trying to implement sip redirection. To do this I'm using javax.servlet.sip.Proxy

```
SipFactory sipFactory = (SipFactory) getServletContext().getAttribute(SIP_FACTORY);
Proxy proxy = request.getProxy();
proxy.setParallel(false);
proxy.setRecordRoute(true);
ArrayList uris = new ArrayList();
SipURI uri2 = sipFactory.createSipURI("48505999666", "some_host");

uris.add(uri2);
proxy.proxyTo(uris);
```

But in From header i got additional prefix in phone number and on my phone i can't see who is calling. Is there any way to modify From header displayName ?

Answer (score 0):

When you say an "additional prefix," do you mean that the proxy is changing the value of the `From` header?  That sounds like incorrect proxy behavior.  What is being sent by the UAC, and what is being sent by the proxy?

According to JSR-289, the `From` header is a system header and thus cannot be modified by a proxy.  At the price of additional complexity,  you could implement a back-to-back user agent (b2bua) instead.

Comment: When I say an "additional prefix" I ment that call center add prefix for example I call form number "48505999667" and in sipUri I have "B1448505999667". And when I proxy this to another phone this prefix makes number "unknown".

Comment: OK, so the `From` header in initial SIP request has extra characters which the UAS does not like.  As stated above, a proxy cannot change the From header.  Is there any other header that the UAS will inspect to determine the caller ID?